# Creating a shell variable programmatically

Tags: bash, shell, environment-variables, evaluation

I have a PHP script which exports a pipe-delimited list of variables like this to STDOUT:

```
DB_HOST|localhost
DB_DATABASE|mydb
DB_USER|postgres
...
```

What I want to do is read them into a Bash script and set them as shell variables to be used by any programs called from inside the shell script, i.e.

```
psql -U $DB_USER -h $DB_HOST -d $DB_DATABASE <<END_OF_SQL
  code...
END_OF_SQL
```

Here's what I did, which isn't working:

```
#!/bin/bash

# We don't need an eval here but just to confirm that it works with eval.
eval export FOO_DOCROOT=/web/gallery

php get_env.php | while read X
    do
    LINE=(`echo $X | tr "\|" "\n"`)
    V="${LINE[0]}=${LINE[1]}"   # Outputs a string, i,e. "FOO_DBHOST=localhost".
    echo "V=$V"
    echo $V
    # This has no effect.
    eval export $V
done;

echo Check the environment
echo /bin/env:
env

# env has FOO_DOCROOT set correctly
# but none of the evals in the DO/DONE loop are set.
```

I've confirmed that the set env strings don't have any whitespace or special characters.  But no matter what permutation of arguments I pass to eval the variables don't get set.

Any ideas?  Is there a security block with creating new shell variables programmatically in bash?

Answer (score 4):

This is all that you need.

```
#!/bin/bash
# script name script1.sh
while IFS="|" ; read VarName Value; do
    export Imported_$VarName=$Value
done
echo Check Enviroment
env |grep DB_
```

For testing I substituted get_env.php with get_env.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
# script name get_env.sh
echo "DB_HOST|localhost
DB_DATABASE|mydb
DB_USER|postgres"
```

Then when I run the command below, I get the following output.

```
~$ ./get_env.sh |./script1.sh 
Check The Environment
Imported_DB_USER=postgres
Imported_DB_DATABASE=mydb
Imported_DB_HOST=localhost
```

Prepending something to variable name can be a security measure in cases where a html form submits names=values to your php script and those are sent to your bash script.

Answer (score 2):

Probably this common bash *gotcha*
[Bash can sometimes start a subshell in a PIPED `while-read' loop. This causes variables introduced within the while-read loop to disappear.](http://fvue.nl/wiki/Bash%3a_Piped_%60while-read%27_loop_starts_subshell)

The usual solution is to store the variables and use them outside the loop.

Comment: Excellent find, Nifle.  Thanks!